# how to loading image in uwp while background worker is running

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, win-universal-app

I am using background worker in my uwp project. Here I want to show the loading image while background worker is running. after completion of background worker task the loading image should be invisible.
How can I do that.

```
BackgroundWorker productPrices = new BackgroundWorker();

productPrices.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(productPrices_Dowork);
productPrices.RunWorkerCompleted += productPrices_RunWorkerCompleted;
productPrices.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
productPrices.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(productPrices_ProgressChanged);
productPrices.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

private async void productPrices_Dowork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    progressring.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        string customerId = Application.Current.Resources[Constants.CUSTOMER_ID].ToString();
        string username = Application.Current.Resources[Constants.EMAIL_ID].ToString();
        string strIpAddress = Application.Current.Resources[Constants.IP_ADDRESS].ToString();
        string strPortNumber = Application.Current.Resources[Constants.PORT_Number].ToString();
        RequestHeader requestHeader = DBHelper.GetRequestHeader(customerId, customerId, username);
        string strStoreLocation = Application.Current.Resources[Constants.STORE_LOCATION].ToString();
        int startIndex = 0;
        await ProductAgent.GetProductPrices(requestHeader, strIpAddress, strPortNumber, strStoreLocation);

    });
}
```

Comment: Definitely we can do that, have you tried anything to make it happened?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: there is actually something build into the UWP platform that you can use. its called `ProgressRing` Would that suit your needs or does it need to be a custom image? If the latter, check out [this page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-progress-ring-for-windows-10-uwp-app/) for some tips

Comment: progress ring is enough but i am not able to show it while background worker is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're setting the visibility of the progress ring in your `DoWork` event handler. This one is run on a background thread, so it should give you an exception along these lines:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in UWP.exe
>
> Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Move this line:

```
progressring.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

...to wherever you call `RunWorkerAsync`. If that's already on a background thread, you need to invoke that bit of code on the UI thread using the dispatcher, e.g.,

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => progressring.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
```

(You could do that from within your `DoWork` event handler too, if you like.)

---

For completeness, a working example. In XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWP.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ProgressRing
            x:Name="progressRing"
            Height="30"
            IsActive="False"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Button
            Content="Go"
            Margin="0,30"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="OnGoClick" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In code-behind:

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnGoClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += OnDoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnRunWorkerCompleted;
        progressRing.IsActive = true;
        progressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void OnDoWork(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        Task.Delay(2000).Wait(); // Pretend to work
    }

    private void OnRunWorkerCompleted(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        progressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        progressRing.IsActive = false;
    }
}
```